# How to download the files in magento

Tags: magento, download, magento-1.7

I uploaded some files for each customer in magento....

Then i listed the customers details with the uploaded file name ..

I need to download the file using magento code

This is the code:

```
public function downloadAction() {
        $entityid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id');
        $customer_data = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($entityid);
        $filename = '';
        if($customer_data){
            $filename = $customer_data->getFileuploadname();
        }
        $filepath = '../uploads/'.$filename;

        if (! is_file ( $filepath ) || ! is_readable ( $filepath )) {
            throw new Exception ( );
        }
        $this->getResponse ()
                    ->setHttpResponseCode ( 200 )
                    ->setHeader ( 'Pragma', 'public', true )
                    ->setHeader ( 'Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true )
                    ->setHeader ( 'Content-type', 'application/force-download' )
                    ->setHeader ( 'Content-Length', filesize($filepath) )
                    ->setHeader ('Content-Disposition', 'inline' . '; filename=' . basename($filepath) );
        $this->getResponse ()->clearBody ();
        $this->getResponse ()->sendHeaders ();
        readfile ( $filepath );
        //exit(0);
    }
```

But it didsplays errors something like:

```
Trace:
#0 D:\wamp\www\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(419): Managecustomers_Users_IndexController->downloadAction()
#1 D:\wamp\www\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('download')
#2 D:\wamp\www\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#3 D:\wamp\www\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#4 D:\wamp\www\mysite\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#5 D:\wamp\www\mysite\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#6 {main}
```

The `uploads` folder is in magento root folder...

How can i download the file....

The `$filename` have the filename uploaded that is coming from database...

**EDIT :**

When i removed the code:

```
 if (! is_file ( $filepath ) || ! is_readable ( $filepath )) {
            throw new Exception ( );
        }
```

Then changed the filepath as :

```
$filepath = 'http://localhost/mysite/uploads/'.$filename;
```

Then downloading done perfectly....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the solution for this type of problems:

```
 public function downloadAction() {
        $entityid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id');
        $customer_data = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($entityid);
        $filename = '';
        if($customer_data){
            $filename = $customer_data->getFileuploadname();
        }
        $filepath = Mage::getBaseDir('base').'/uploads/'.$filename;

        if (! is_file ( $filepath ) || ! is_readable ( $filepath )) {
            throw new Exception ( );
        }
        $this->getResponse ()
                    ->setHttpResponseCode ( 200 )
                    ->setHeader ( 'Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true )
                     ->setHeader ( 'Pragma', 'public', true )
                    ->setHeader ( 'Content-type', 'application/force-download' )
                    ->setHeader ( 'Content-Length', filesize($filepath) )
                    ->setHeader ('Content-Disposition', 'attachment' . '; filename=' . basename($filepath) );
        $this->getResponse ()->clearBody ();
        $this->getResponse ()->sendHeaders ();
        readfile ( $filepath );
        exit;
    }
```

The problem based on the file path issues.....now its solved....

Comment: It is prefered to use `_prepareDownloadResponse()` as suggested by @WonderLand as it does not need `exit`

Comment: I am trying to implement the same solution but it is giving me error as 'Call to a member function setHttpResponseCode() on a non-object' can you please let me know is there any other class which needs to include in file?
Thank you.

Comment: Also tried to use  _prepareDownloadResponse  but not working.

Answer (score 12):

What about use Magento code ? ... `_prepareDownloadResponse()`

```
 public function downloadAction()
    {
       $filename = '';
       if($customer_data){
          $filename = $customer_data->getFileuploadname();
       }
       $filepath = Mage::getBaseDir('base').'/uploads/'.$filename;

        if ($filename) {
            try {
                $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($filename, array('type' => 'filename', 'value' => $filepath));

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($filepath . ' not found');
            $this->_redirect('adminhtml/cache');
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This should be definitely the accepted answer. Thanks @WonderLand

Comment: Is it possible to download multiple files with _prepareDownloadResponse ?

Comment: Is it possible to download multiple files with _prepareDownloadResponse ?

Answer (score 0):

To use Magento's `_prepareDownloadResponse()` in a controller action when you have access to the file path do the following in your controller class:

```
public function downloadAction()
{
    $filePath = '/this/is/an/filepath';

    return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse(basename($filePath), file_get_contents($filePath));
}
```